# Права доступа к страницам в linux x86_64

Tags: linux, memory, x86-64, виртуальная-память

Изучаю как устроена атака на переполнение буфера. Написал вот такую программу

```
typedef void(*Function)();
int main() {
    const char* shell = "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90";
    Function f = (Function)shell;
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

shell - пара десятков nop-ов.(0x90 - опкод nop-a).
Пошагово прошелся по ней в gdb и она падает от segfault при вызове f, а точнее при выполнении инструкции

```
callq    *%rdx
```

При этом в rdx записан адрес 0x4005d8( Именно по этому адресу располагаются nop-ы). И все это можно было бы объяснить тем, что адрес 0x4005d8 относится к странице у которой не выставлено право на исполнение, но:

1) Вот вывод утилиты pmap для этого процесса

```
26040:   ./main
0000000000400000      4K r-x-- main
0000000000600000      4K r---- main
0000000000601000      4K rw--- main
0000000001c65000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f40de3ce000   1792K r-x-- libc-2.23.so
00007f40de58e000   2048K ----- libc-2.23.so
00007f40de78e000     16K r---- libc-2.23.so
00007f40de792000      8K rw--- libc-2.23.so
00007f40de794000     16K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f40de798000    152K r-x-- ld-2.23.so
00007f40de995000     12K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f40de9bd000      4K r---- ld-2.23.so
00007f40de9be000      4K rw--- ld-2.23.so
00007f40de9bf000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
00007ffd8e874000    132K rw---   [ stack ]
00007ffd8e924000     12K r----   [ anon ]
00007ffd8e927000      8K r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000      4K r-x--   [ anon ]
 total             4356K
```

И если я правильно понимаю что тут написано, то у диапазона адресов 0х400000-0х60000 есть право на исполнение.

2) Что подтверждает предыдущий пункт: адрес функции main был 0х400507 что довольно близко к последовательности nop-ов.

Однако если в rdx положить адрес main то никакого segfault-а не происходит. Проясните, пожалуйста, что не так.

Comment: Как вы думаете, что будет исполнять процессор в вашем случае? Даже представим возможность исполняемого стека.

Comment: @0andriy будет исполнять nop-ы, а я смогу это увидеть в дебаггере. И потом эти nop-ы лежат не в стеке,  значение указателя shell было равно 0x4005d8 что судя по выводу pmap -  страница с правом на исполнение.

Comment: Да, вы правы, nop’ы лежат не на стеке. Благодаря модификатору  const их упаковщик должен положить в RO секцию.

Answer (score 3):

Учитывая, что сегмент константных данных (а именно туда попадает `const char* shell`) отображается без права на исполнение, скорее всего, вы столкнулись с ASLR.

ASLR (*Address Space Layout Randomisation*, разбиение адресного пространства случайным образом) — это механизм, который как раз и направлен против шелл-атак, полагающихся на фиксированный адрес тех или иных участков памяти. Он разбрасывает программу, библиотеки и стек случайным образом по всей виртуальной памяти, доступной программе, причём из запуска в запуск результат подобного распределения отличается.

При первом запуске (под gdb) адрес `0x4005d8` попадал в сегмент неизменяемых данных программы (на это указывают права доступа сегмента, да и `const`-переменные находятся только там). При втором же запуске (для pmap) по тому адресу стал располагаться сегмент кода.

Если вы хотите получить согласованный результат, запускайте pmap параллельно с gdb, в другом окне или вкладке консоли.

---

*(Немного о праве на исполнение блока памяти)*

Начиная с версии 2.3.23, Linux имеет встроенную поддержку DEP.

DEP (*Data Execution Prevention*, предотвращение выполнения данных) — это механизм, направленный на запрет исполнения кода там, где должны лежать данные (к примеру, в стеке или сегменте данных). Он работает за счёт того, что к уже существующим флагам прав доступа к странице (чтение, запись, доступ только из режима ядра и т. д.) был добавлен ещё один (запрет на исполнение), который операционная система устанавливает для всех страниц, не соответствующих сегментам кода исполняемых файлов (а `main()` как раз и лежит в подобном сегменте).

Единственное, где может сработать ваш шелл — это в областях памяти, созданных при помощи `mmap()` с *одновременно* выставленными флагами `PROT_EXEC` и `PROT_WRITE`.